# assigning event handlers to svg elements programmatically

Tags: javascript, svg

I've started to do a visualization using svg. it's a simple column chart thing and working fine that far. I'm loading the data from an external XML file and display a column chart. 
Now I want to add a hover-effect, that will change the color of the bar when hovering a column. 
So the question is how do I add an eventhandler to a previously generated svg element. 
I tried different ways:
(1) When generating the element trying to add the eventhandler already:

```
newElement.onmouseclick="highlightOn(this)";
```

(2) adding the event handler this supposedly more advanced way I don't know how to select the right element that fired the event inside the SVG.

```
newElement.addEventListener("mouseover", highlightOn, false)
```

(3) some forum showed this as a possibility (doesn't work either: contentDocument returns null)

```
theSVG.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("svg hovered");
    var svgDoc = theSVG.contentDocument; //get the inner DOM of alpha.svg
    console.log(svgDoc);
    var allColums= svgDoc.getElementsByTagName("rect");
    for (var i = 0; i < allColums.length; i++) {
        allColums[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            console.log("clicked!"); })
    };

});
```

so all in all, I'm quite confused and have no idea how to proceed.
Here is how I'm generating the svg:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allLogs.length; i++) {
    //reading data
    date        =allLogs[i].getElementsByTagName("date")[0].firstChild.data;
    console.log("date "+date);
    time5000m   =allLogs[i].getElementsByTagName("TimeFivethousandMeter")[0].firstChild.data;
    if (time5000m==" ") {time5000m=0;};
    console.log("time 5000m"+time5000m);
    //adding data to SVG
    //>> colum
    var newElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'rect'); //Create a rect in SVG's namespace
    newElement.setAttribute("width",width); 
    newElement.setAttribute("height",time5000m*scaleFactor); 
    var xPos=width*i+i*offset+sideMargins/2;
    newElement.setAttribute("x",xPos); 
    var yPos=height-time5000m*scaleFactor-verticalMargin/2;
    newElement.setAttribute("y", yPos);
    newElement.style.fill = "#cf004e"; //Set fill colour
    newElement.style.opacity="0.75";
    theSVG.appendChild(newElement);
};
```

How to deal with this?

Comment: Re snippet #2: Inside the function highlightOn, the `this` keyword refers to the element that (a) the event is attached to and (b) the fired the event

Comment: @enzflep: that's what I thought to so I had a function like this
function highlightOn(obj){
 obj.style.fill="#543";
}
but it didn't work

Comment: no, it wouldn't. The variable passed to the function is the _event_, not the object that triggered it. As I said, use the `this` keyword. I.e `function highlightOn(e){ this.style.fill = '#543;'; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your first attempt:

```
newElement.onmouseclick="highlightOn(this)";
```

You have one mistake: `onmouseclick` should just be `onclick`

I've had trouble using `this` in mouse events, so the best method I've used is to set an ID for the element in question, then use a helper function to assign to the onlick, so add something like this to your element creation loop:

```
var id = 'el'+i;
newElement.id = id;
newElement.onclick = funcHighlightOn(id);
```

Then, use a function like this that you can use to assign the onclick action:

```
function funcHighlightOn(id) {
   return function() {
      highlightOn(id);
   }
}
```

The reason for the weirdness of the above is that it's difficult to pass parameters (in this case, the element's ID) into the mouse events when assigned this way.

Comment: thanks! that one works. just adding a line selecting the element using the ID

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things odd here.  First, why in (3) are you trying to add click handlers inside a click handler?  It may be that every click is being intercepted by the SVG click handler, and all you are ever doing is replacing the rect click handlers.

Why don't you just add the click handler when you create each `<rect>` in the first place?  Add your handler to newElement when you append it.

Comment: I interpreted the OP was listing different solutions he tried - not all at once.